# Sugar momma wants my bank login info — is this a scam?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I met a women online, through a website meant to help fetish-seekers network. After we had talked for only a couple of hours, she told me she wanted me to be her sugar baby and will pay me weekly. However, she wants my bank login info to link accounts. Is this a scam?

Comment: No one needs your bank login to send you money. Think about it. Your boss pays you several times a month. Did you ever give THEM your bank login? Sugar baby/daddy sites are LOADED with scammers.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone asks for your bank login information, it is a scam. Period. There is no legitimate reason for anyone but you and the bank to have that level of access.

Comment: Even the *bank* does not (or should not) have your login info.

Comment: When you got your bank account you signed an agreement that you would not share login info.

Comment: Chepner: True, they have their own access, and should never need to know yours.

Related: Any time anyone asks for an invoice to be paid in gift cards, it's a scam. Any time anyone demands to be paid in cryptocurrency, especially if they contacted you rather than the other way around, it is probably a scam. 

If it feels wrong, it probably is wrong. Paranoia is not enough.